# Check a textbox if contains numbers AND Strings

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, integer, c-strings

i'm a new programmer and i have a project which i want the textbox contain letters and at least 1 number.Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("name.txt");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid name!\nPlease Try Again!");
            }
            else if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]*$") && System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The field accepts only letters and at least one number!\nPlease Try Again");
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Player added Successfully!");
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.Show();
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if your string contains only Numbers and Letters you can use [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletterordigit?view=net-5.0#System_Char_IsLetterOrDigit_System_Char_) combined with [`String.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) to check if all of the characters in that string match the given type.

Furthermore I also used [`Char.IsDigit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-5.0#System_Char_IsDigit_System_Char_) combined with [`String.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) to check if at least one characters was a number.

**Example:**

```cs
string s = textBox1.Text;

// Check if all of the letters are only Letters and Digits
// and if atleast one is a Digit.
bool result = !s.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit) || !s.Any(Char.IsDigit);
```

---

I also added [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-5.0) to add a check if the user entered text but it only consist of spaces. Furthermore I encased the code in a using block for the [`Streamwriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0) so it automatically calls the `Dispose()` method after it has left the using block.

**Example in your Code:**

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("name.txt")) {
    string s = textBox1.Text;
    // Check if string consits of only whitespaces, nothign or if it is null.
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid name!\nPlease Try Again!");
    }
    // Check if all of the letters are only Letters and Digits
    // and if atleast one is a Digit.
    else if (!s.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit) || !s.Any(Char.IsDigit)) {
        MessageBox.Show("The field accepts only letters and 
            + at least one number!\nPlease Try Again");
    }
    else {
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        MessageBox.Show("Player added Successfully!");
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
    }
}
```